# System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue() - Downgrading .NET version - method signature missing

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

To get a .NET console application running on Server 2003, we're having to downgrade one of our core libraries from .NET 4.5 to 4.0. Among other things, this library has a class that performs some reflection, cycling through an object's properties to get their values using     `Propertyinfo.GetValue()`

According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `PropertyInfo.GetValue (Object)` is in .NET 4.5 only. In .NET 4.0, [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exists, but in the form `PropertyInfo.GetValue (Object, Object[])` (the extra parameter is to know how to handle indexed properties).

If we're to downgrade this code, we need to know what happens when `PropertyInfo.GetValue Method (Object)` encounters an indexed property, so we can mirror this functionality using `PropertyInfo.GetValue Method (Object, Object[])`. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation isn't clear about this, but inspecting the implementation in a decompiler shows that `property.GetValue(obj)` just calls `property.GetValue(obj, null)` without any checks whatsoever, and without catching any exceptions whatsoever. Any exception that you would get from `property.GetValue(obj)` is therefore *exactly* the exception that you would get from `property.GetValue(obj, null)`, and you should have no problems updating your calls.